# Creating Wrapper to redirect Console output with 100ms delay between lines c#

Tags: c#, redirect, console, output, wrapper

I have a game which has a console and trying to redirect that output live. At the minute all I really need to do is add the output to a text box, then I can adapt it later.

I have been able to get it to work by reading to end of the Console but because it is live it will only write when the game is closed.

I realise I will need a short delay between lines, I'm just unsure of how I could redirect the console output line by line in `C#`

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the Console.SetOut method.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could then implement the [TextWriter interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) to write to the TextBox.

So something like:

```
public class BoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _textBox;

    public TextBoxWriter (TextBox textBox)
    {
        _textBox = textBox;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _textBox.AppendText(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. I discovered by further research you could create a method but when output data is received so I just wrote the data whenever the method was triggered.